# How do I create a VecDeque from a vector?

Tags: vector, rust

I am trying to quickly create a `VecDeque` using the `::from()`. I have the following Rust code:

```
use std::collections::VecDeque;

fn main() {
    let ring = VecDeque::from([1, 2, 3]);
    println!("{:?}", ring);
}
```

I get the following compiler error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::collections::VecDeque<_>: std::convert::From<[{integer}; 3]>` is not satisfied
 --> src/main.rs:4:16
  |
4 |     let ring = VecDeque::from([1, 2, 3]);
  |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::convert::From<[{integer}; 3]>` is not implemented for `std::collections::VecDeque<_>`
  |
  = help: the following implementations were found:
            <std::collections::VecDeque<T> as std::convert::From<std::vec::Vec<T>>>
  = note: required by `std::convert::From::from`
```

This looks like the `VecDeque` collection doesn't implement the `from` trait, but  [the docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.VecDeque.html#implementations) suggest that it does. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
use std::collections::VecDeque;
use std::iter::FromIterator;
fn main() {
    let ring = VecDeque::from_iter(&[1, 2, 3]);
    println!("{:?}", ring);
}
```

It only implements `From<Vec<T>>` and `[...]` isn't a `Vec`. Since it implements `FromIterator`, you can use any kind of iterator as a source with `from_iter`. `&[1, 2, 3]` is because `from_iter` takes an `Iterator`.

Comment: That's great, thanks. After reading your explanation, I found I could also do `let ring = VecDeque::from(vec![1, 2, 3]);` without having an extra `use` statement. Are there any problems with this approach?

Comment: @SimonBrahan Not really – it will do more heap allocations than the from_iter approach, but that's unlikely to be relevant.  But why would you want to avoid the additional `use` statement?  It doesn't hurt in any way.

Comment: @SimonBrahan Nope; they're technically different, but practically speaking `Vec` is used pervasively through out all rust code. Do whichever feels more ergonomic to you.

Comment: ...but this only works because integers are `Copy`, right?

Comment: This is a bad answer. It creates a `VecDeque<&'static i32>` instead of `VecDeque<i32>`. Also, the most usual way to use `FromIterator` is with `Iterator::collect`, which doesn't need to be `use`d. `let ring: VecDeque<_> = [1, 2, 3].iter().copied().collect();` would be a much more reasonable interpretation of the code in the question.

Comment: @SvenMarnach It no longer does more heap allocations, `VecDeque::From<Vec>` "is guaranteed to run in O(1) and not re-allocate the Vec's buffer." In fact the `from_iter` approach now delegates to `Vec::from_iter(…).into()`

Comment: @speedstyle You are right. This wasn't documented at the time I wrote my comment, so at that time we didn't have that guarantee (though the behaviour was probably already the same).

Comment: @SvenMarnach I think it actually wasn't the same, VecDeque changed from (head, tail) to (head, len) in 2022. To have full look different to empty, `tail` can't hit `head`, which requires an empty space, while `vec!` allocates exactly enough for the literal. (I guess for contiguous deques they could've made an exception? And it might be a free realloc or optimize out. But yeah no guarantees)

Answer (score 20):

Alternatively, you can also use [`From<Vec<T>>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.VecDeque.html#impl-From%3CVec%3CT%3E%3E):

> ```
> fn from(other: Vec<T>) -> VecDeque<T>
> ```
>
> Turn a `Vec<T>` into a `VecDeque<T>`.
>
> This avoids reallocating where possible, but the conditions for that are strict, and subject to change, and so shouldn't be relied upon unless the `Vec<T>` came from `From<VecDeque<T>>` and hasn't been reallocated.

Example:

```
let vector: Vec<i32> = vec![0, 1, 2];
let vec_queue: VecDeque<i32> = VecDeque::from(vector);
```